# What is the BigDecimal Rounding mode for financial transactions in India?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I know that for US the rounding mode is

```
RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN
```

Also known as Bankers mode, what is the government approved rounding mode in India?

Comment: You are supposed to do research on your own before posting here (see [ask]). A simple google query like "*India which rounding mode*" yields me sites like [this](https://blogs.tallysolutions.com/gst-rounding-rules-for-tax-values/). Which explain that they use *normal rounding* (i.e. half-up).

Comment: Did you do any **research** of your own? My quick research found that India uses `HALF_UP`: *"[should be rounded off to the nearest rupee; i.e. fraction of 50 paise and above shall be rounded off to the next higher rupee and fraction of less than 50 paise shall be ignored](https://www.rbi.org.in/commonman/English/Scripts/Notification.aspx?Id=241)"*

Comment: @Zabuza That article actually says to use "normal" rounding and defines that as `HALF_UP`: *"50 Paise or more, it is rounded upward ... less than 50 Paise, it is rounded downward"*

Comment: *"I know that for US the rounding mode is `RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN`"* Really? How do you "know" that? Please provide reference. And just because it is called "bankers rounding" does mean that bankers are using it. E.g. this articles "[Treasury Futures Price Rounding Conventions](https://www.cmegroup.com/education/articles-and-reports/treasury-futures-price-rounding-conventions.html)" says to use `HALF_UP`: *"(3.1.3)  Round result (3.1.2) to the nearest penny.  If result (3.1.2) ends in a half-penny, then round up."*

Comment: This is the sort of detail you would ask your client. If they don't know show them some examples and ask them what they expect to happen. It's good to know this but it's the client who should decide.

Comment: Seems like i have pissed off many people with my question!
Thanks for the people who have put in effort to answer the question.

Moderators can delete the question if they find that this question goes gainst standard guidelines for how to ask

Comment: It's not against StackOverflow rules or anything. It's just that it fulfills the requirements to down-vote. Because it does not show research effort. This reflects that the question is not of a particularly good *quality*. But it is still a valid question that is conform with all rules here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the commonly used mode in India is `HALF_UP`:

> should be **rounded** off to the **nearest rupee**; i.e. fraction of **50 paise and above** shall be **rounded** off to the **next higher rupee** and fraction of l**ess than 50 paise** shall be **ignored**.

Sources:

- [Reserve Bank of India (RBI/2006-2007/315,  RPCD.CO.RF.BC.No.67 /07.02.01/2006-07)](https://www.rbi.org.in/commonman/English/Scripts/Notification.aspx?Id=241)
- [GST India (Goods and Services Tax)](https://blogs.tallysolutions.com/gst-rounding-rules-for-tax-values/)

Note that this does not necessarily mean that this mode is used for all applications in India.